# Characterizing direct sums

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $U,V$ be vector spaces. Let $T: U \to V$ be a linear map. The codimension of $T$ is defined to be $\mathrm{dim}(V) - \mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{im}(T))$.

My questions are:

(1) given the subspace $\mathrm{im}(T)$ when does there exist another subspace $Z$ of $V$ such that $\mathrm{im}(T) \oplus Z = V$.

(2) given a space $Z$ such that $\mathrm{im}(T) \oplus Z = V$ does it imply anything for $Z$?

What I know: If the codimension is finite, that is, $V/\mathrm{im}(T)$ has finite dimension then there does exist such $Z$ as in(1). I also know that if $Z$ is finite dimensional and $\mathrm{im}(T) \oplus Z = V$ then $\mathrm{im}(T)$ is closed.

But what happens if the condition that one of the spaces is finite dimensional is dropped?